# Elementary algebraic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

Let real $x$ with $0\le x \le 1$ and integer $n$ with $n \ge 2$. Show that 
\begin{align}
f(x,n) = &\;  ((1+x)^n - 1)\cdot(2(1 - x)^{n - 1} + 1) + \\
 & +((1 - x)^n - 1)\cdot((1+x)^{n - 1} + (1 - x)^{n - 1} + 1) \ge 0
\end{align}

Computer simulations show that it holds for $2 \le n \le 20$.

For $n=2$ we have 
$f(x,n=2) = 2x^2(1-x) \ge 0$,
for $n=3$ 
we have 
$f(x,n=3) =x^2(8(x-\frac{3}{4})^2 + \frac{3}{2})\ge 0
$, so this is a good start.

The whole task looks rather elementary but I am missing the clue for general $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed with induction. $f(x,2)$ is clearly non-negative. Now assume that the result holds for $f(x,n)$ and prove that it holds for $f(x,n+1)$. Does this help at all? Writing out $f(x,n+1)$ might be some annoying simplification, but I usually use a Computer Algebra System for this type of thing anyway.

Comment: Generally this is a good advice. However the resulting polynomial is generally of degree $2n-1$ so this will become tricky.

Comment: I have decided to abandon a direct induction route. I've done some partial work to show that the inequality is true when x is 0 or 1. Now, I suppose that if you can show that f(x,n) for x in (0,1) is non-negative, then that would complete things. I'm unsure of how to proceed from here, but I will continue to ponder it.

Comment: I thought of something. Try to show that f(x,n) is monotonically increasing for x in (0,1) for each natural number n. You can proceed with this via induction, and then it would give you what you need to show that f(x,n) is non-negative, as f(0,n) < f(1,n). If showing monotonicity is too difficult or if the function is not monotonic, we will need a different approach.